# Relation beetween sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering how can one define the notion of relation beetween sets.
I mean, if $X$ is a set, a relation on $X$ is a subset of $X \times X$.
But this definition does not apply to relations beetween sets, since in that case $X$ should be the "set of all sets".

What's the proper definition in this case?

Comment: Well from what I understand, you don't need $X$ to be a set in order to define $X \times X$ so you could probably just define it for classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that the set of all sets doesn't exist, then you should be familiar with the term "class". Classes are collections of sets which are not necessarily sets themselves.

Now we can talk about classes which are classes of ordered pairs, and these are relations on sets. For example, the class $\{\langle A,B\rangle\mid\forall a(a\in A\rightarrow a\in B)\}$ is the class of $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it necessary invoke class theory to answer this question. You agree that a relation $R$ on set $X$ is just a subset of $X\times X$. If the elements of $X$ are themselves sets (always the case in ZFC), then $R$ is a relation between sets.

Comment: I think it's necessary when the domain of the relation is potentially the "set of all sets". The example I have in mind is the equivalence $\sim$ beetween sets: $A \sim B$ means that there exist a biunivocal function $f:A\rightarrow B$.

Comment: @pppqqq You started out by saying that $X$ is just "a set." If $X$ was *a family of sets*, there would be no problem defining relations on $X$. It doesn't follow that $X$ must be the so-called set of all sets. The "in this case" in your posting was a bit ambiguous. By your comment, I take it that you meant, what if $X$ was the set of all sets? Sorry, I can't help you there.